# JavaFX - ArrayList of type X

Tags: arraylist, javafx, java-8

I am having trouble to understand how can I pass the values retrieved from an "ObservableList list" into a Persistence operation (DAO) which is int so then I can save the data into the database.

The method which perform the Insert into tablex.table works as expected being an int.

When I perform the output of "ObservableList list" I get the response:

```
      To save content: [field1, field2, field3]
```

which is the response expected.

Now, I need to send that content to populate 3 columns on the db, which is executed by:

```
 public int createStmt(BeanOne beanOne) throws SQLException;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution.

What needs to be implemented is:

```
    NameDAO dataToBeAdded= new NameDAO();
    dataToBeAdded.setFirstString(firstTextField.getText());
    dataToBeAdded.setSecondString(secondTextField.getText());
    dataToBeAdded.setThirdString(thirdTextField.getText());

    this.NameDAO.theIntDAOMethod(dataToBeAdded);
```